# Why is there no /usr/bin in Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, path

I am a Linux user spending some time in Windows and I am trying to understand
some of the Windows paradigms instead of fighting them. I notice that each
program installed in the traditional manner adds the executables to

```
C:\Program Files
```

and then adds a shortcut to the Desktop / Start Menu containing the entire path.
However, there is no common directory with links to the software, i.e.
`C:\bin\bar.exe` which would link to

```
C:\Program Files\foo\bar.exe
```

Therefore, after installing an application the only way to use the application
is via the menus or by navigating to the executable in the filesystem. One
cannot simply `Win-R` to open the run dialogue and then type `bar` or `bar.exe`
as is possible with `notepad` or `mspaint`. I realize that Windows 8 improves on
this with the otherwise horrendous Start Screen which does support typing the
name of the app, but again this depends on the app having registered itself for
such.

Would I be doing any harm by adding `C:\Program Files` recursively to the
Windows path? I do realize that there will be name collisions (i.e.
uninstall.exe) but could there be other issues?

Comment: Note that the search box in the start menu (which allows you to find a program by typing its name) was introduced in Windows Vista, so this feature is not new in Windows 8.

Comment: Having the app 'registered' by the installer into the start menu is the same as the application creating the link in `/usr/bin/` - it relies on the application or installer doing it.

Comment: @JamesSnell: Right, but the Linux paradigm end result is an executable that is available on the global path. The Windows paradigm end result is that one must know the full path. I'm not interested in a specific directory of links to all executables per se, but rather having all the user-run executables in the path, and additionally understanding why Windows doesn't have this paradigm.

Comment: In the DOS days, typically programs would make a subdirectory off of C:\ and place all files, including temporary, configuration, data, and executable files in that subdirectory.  Even today you'll find some software (typically programs that have been around a long time) that does this (e.g. UltraTax).  This sort of continued with Windows 3.11, the 9x windows, and even through the NT line to maintain compatibility with the 9x line.  It's getting a teensy more sensible IMHO with UAC and default permissions now starting to try to enforce more sensible things.

Comment: What if there are two programs named bar?

Comment: There is a project named Chocolatey which defines one common directory for its installed programs, similar to /usr/bin. But it has not gained much traction.

Comment: Windows does not pretend to be any sort of UNIX or Linux (even with WSL). Rather it tends to be like Apple's OS X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually there should not be any issues. However, you need to watch out for two things:

- Avoid name collisions. In particular, make sure the standard path components (like `C:\windows` etc.) come first, so no system utility is hidden in the path.
- The `PATH` variable [may not contain more than 8191 characters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473/en-us). So if you have many program folders that you want to add, you may have to pick and choose. If you assume an average path length of 50 characters per program, that gives you space for about 160 programs in the PATH.

The reason this is not done by default is probably simply that the command line is used relatively rarely on Windows, so there was never a pressing need to have everything in the path. Most programs that need to invoke other programs have adapted to this, and use the full path for invocations.

Finally, if you would like to work on the command line a lot, like on Linux, I recommend you install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/). It provides a Linux-like environment on Windows, and lets you work on the command line. It also maintains its own `PATH` variable, which you can customize without impacting other Windows applications.

Comment: Thank you, I actually am using Cygwin in mintty for most things now. However, Python is a beast and needs the original `cmd`, even with the `-i` flag.

Comment: @dotancohen You can [use WSL instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide) if you're running Windows 10. Works virtually perfectly for python development.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends on the type of program you are talking about. If you
are talking about programs that use shared libraries (DLLs):

```
C:\Program Files
```

is the correct place for them. You cannot put the files for these programs into
the same folder because they are likely to have [name collisions](//wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell). If you
are talking about programs that use static libraries (no DLLs):

```
C:\ProgramData\Bin
```

is the correct place for them. This is akin to:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

on Linux. This directory is available via a [folder variable](https://web.archive.org/web/20180606140951/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/help/folder-variables):

```
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
```

If you need to get programs with shared libraries onto your Path, you can
symlink them:

```sh
mklink C:\ProgramData\Bin\alfa.exe "C:\Program Files\Alfa\alfa.exe"
```